# Docker for Windows Kubernetes pod gets ImagePullBackOff after creating a new deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

I have successfully built Docker images and ran them in a Docker swarm.  When I attempt to build an image and run it with Docker Desktop's Kubernetes cluster:

```
docker build -t myimage -f myDockerFile .
```

(the above successfully creates an image in the docker local registry)

```
kubectl run myapp --image=myimage:latest
```

(as far as I understand, this is the same as using the kubectl create deployment command)

The above command successfully creates a deployment, but when it makes a pod, the pod status always shows:

```
NAME                                   READY  STATUS            RESTARTS  AGE 
myapp-<a random alphanumeric string>   0/1    ImagePullBackoff  0         <age>
```

I am not sure why it is having trouble pulling the image - does it maybe not know where the docker local images are?

Comment: Is your kubectl pointed to some other context? e.g. minikube

Comment: No, good check though, I can see in Docker for Desktop on the kubernetes dropdown (?) that it has docker-for-desktop selected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the exact same problem.  Boils down to the `imagePullPolicy`:

```
PC:~$ kubectl explain deployment.spec.template.spec.containers.imagePullPolicy
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  extensions/v1beta1

FIELD:    imagePullPolicy <string>

DESCRIPTION:
     Image pull policy. One of Always, Never, IfNotPresent. Defaults to Always
     if :latest tag is specified, or IfNotPresent otherwise. Cannot be updated.
     More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images#updating-images
```

Specifically, the part that says: *Defaults to Always if :latest tag is specified*.

That means, you created a local image, but, because you use the `:latest` it will try to find it in whatever remote repository you configured (by default docker hub) rather than using your local.  Simply change your command to:

```
kubectl run myapp --image=myimage:latest --image-pull-policy Never
```

or

```
kubectl run myapp --image=myimage:latest --image-pull-policy IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Holly sh%t. This should be in every tutorial out there. Spent hours trying to figure out how to share image. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same ImagePullBack error while running a pod deployment with a YAML file, also on Docker Desktop.

For anyone else that finds this via Google (like I did), the imagePullPolicy that Lucas mentions above can also be set in the deployment yaml file. See the spec.templage.spec.containers.imagePullPolicy in the yaml snippet below (3 lines from the bottom).

I added that and my app deployed successfully into my local kube cluser, using the kubectl yaml deploy command: kubectl apply -f .\Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: web-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-app
        image: node-web-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify where `myimage:latest` is hosted, but essentially `ImagePullBackoff` means that I cannot pull the image because either:

- You don't have networking setup in your Docker VM that can get to your Docker registry (Docker Hub?)
- `myimage:latest` doesn't exist in your registry or is misspelled.
- `myimage:latest` requires credentials (you are pulling from a private registry). You can take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) to configure container credentials in a Pod.

Comment: I thought so.  I see a way to expose registries through the Docker-for-Desktop / Settings / Daemon, but don't know if that will also expose the image repository.