# Kubernetes overlay mounts and rsync

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to tweak my Kubernetes-based app to make it more development-friendly. I'm using `kustomize` to add some extra containers into my `app-deployment`. It looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: php-src
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: nginx-src
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: webpack-src
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        - name: lsyncd
          image: axiom/rsync-server
          ports:
            - name: sshd
              containerPort: 22
            - name: rsyncd
              containerPort: 873
          env:
            - name: USERNAME
              value: user
            - name: PASSWORD
              value: pass
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-src
              mountPath: /data/php
            - name: nginx-src
              mountPath: /data/nginx
            - name: webpack-src
              mountPath: /data/webpack
        - name: nginx
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-src
              mountPath: /app
        - name: php
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-src
              mountPath: /app
        - name: webpack
          image: dreg.mpen.ca/kymark/webpack
          imagePullPolicy: Never  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043058/65387
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8082
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: http
              path: /assets/manifest.json
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 60
          command: ['node','--max_old_space_size=20000','node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server']
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webpack-src
              mountPath: /app
```

Basically, I've added a new rsync server with 3 volumes corresponding with the 3 different containers that I want to upload code to. This part is working great; I can rsync my code into the containers and it shows up instantly.

However, the nginx, PHP, and webpack images already have a bit of code in that `/app` directory (like `node_modules` and `vendor`). When I mount over the top of it, it disappears (which makes sense, since I'm mounting an `emptyDir`). But what I would like to do instead is use an overlay mount so that any code I upload will be 'overlayed' on top of what's already there.

Can I do that? How?

Comment: This is not completely impossible on **kubernetes** but as you can see [here](https://itnext.io/using-overlay-mounts-with-kubernetes-960375c05959) it's quite a tedious task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **Kubernetes** mounts, unlike **Docker** mounts do not allow mounting one directory over the other. Potential `VOLUME` lines from the `Dockerfile` do not matter.

A common solution for your use-case is, to use an **init container** to set up the [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir), before the **main container** is started. So basically you specify the `emptyDir` as a volume mount in both the **init container** and the **main container** and have the **init container** copy the files into the `emptyDir`.

Additionally, there are two projects that offer different solutions to what you are trying to achieve:

- https://github.com/ksync/ksync
- https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence

Using one of those you would not need the custom `rsync` and **init container** setup in your overlay.